# How do I snap the cursor to selected bone?(python)

Tags: python

How do I snap the cursor to selected bone?(python)

`bpy.ops.view3d.snap_cursor_to_selected()` doesn't work

```
arm = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
empty = bpy.data.objects['Empty']
context.scene.objects.active = arm
#do snapping here
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bone = arm.data.edit_bones['Bone']
bone.head.xyz = empty.location
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Only adds to the armature :(

Comment: bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].cursor.location = some_vector ?

Answer (score 3):

**Set cursor**

Given an example of snapping cursor to active edit bone.  *ie* armature object is `ob = context.object` and the active edit bone is `bone = context.active_bone`

The cursor is in scene, global or world coordinates. Bones are in local space.  Multiply local space coordinates by object world matrix to get global coordinates.

An operator that begins with `bpy.ops.view3d` is designed to run in the 3d view. Running from py console or text editor most likely will produce an invalid context error.

However it is simplest to set the values directly

**In 2.7x**

Set `Scene.cursor_location`  in edit mode to active bone

```
scene = context.scene
bone = context.active_bone
scene.cursor_location = context.object.matrix_world * bone.matrix.translation
```

Snap to Selected requires summing all selected bones locations and dividing by their number to get an average location.

I have used `bone.matrix.translation` which is the equivalent of `bone.head`.

```
from mathutils import Vector
local_loc = sum([b.matrix.translation for b in context.selected_bones, Vector()) / len(context.selected_bones)
# and then setting 
scene.cursor_location = context.object.matrix_world * local_loc
```

Alternatively from using context could for example snap to edit bone "Bone" of the armature object "Armature"

```
ob = scene.objects.get("Armature") # by name
if ob and ob.type == 'ARMATURE': # check exists and is armature.
    bone = ob.data.edit_bones.get("Bone")
```

In 2.8x can set both the translation and rotation of the `Scene.cursor` object by setting the `matrix` property

```
scene = context.scene
bone = context.active_bone
scene.cursor.matrix = context.object.matrix_world @ bone.matrix.translation

scene.tag_update() # updates location and rotation of cursor to bone head as soon as view is  redrawn.
```