# How do I update the cursor matrix in a Python script properly?

Tags: python, add-on, 3d-cursor

I am using the line below to change the cursor location in my  addon script. It works but the change is not shown immediately, I can see the new position if I change the frame.

`bpy.context.scene.cursor.matrix = bpy.context.object.matrix_world`

I tried this line but it has no affect.

`bpy.context.view_layer.update()`

How do I force some kind of view update so that the cursor moves to the new location after its matrix is modified?

thanks

Comment: Related. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/165697/15543   consider setting cursor loc & rot with values from decomposed world matrix.

Comment: .. the tag redraw method was used there, as noticed setting the matrix does not flag an update.. Another workaround is to set the the rotation mode to itself after setting matrix.  However as mentioned above may as well toggle into quat, set from decompose values, toggle back.